# On resize recalculate height and "destroy script" at viewport < 680

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, resize

I use a script on my site, it calculates the highest height of an other div with the same .sh class. Both get the same height.
This works but on viewport < 680 it doesn't need to work.
Also on resize the viewport the height isn't updated/recalculated.

Can anyone help me out with this?

I made a fiddle with an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/ctb9f3c1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(resizeTheHeights);
function resizeTheHeights() {
    var allHeights = [];
    $('.sh').each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        allHeights.push(thisHeight);
    });
    var highestHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, allHeights);
    $('.sh').height(highestHeight);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it could be achieved using pure CSS - see Flexbox

Comment: I don't want to use flexbox because of IE :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated a solution that should work. You should call the funtion on resize event, and add a check within the function to return if width of window less than 680.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function init() {
    resizeTheHeights();
    $( window ).resize(function() { //this is for on resize trigger of this function
       resizeTheHeights();
    });
}());
function resizeTheHeights(allHeights ) {
    if ($( window ).width() < 680) {
       $('.sh').height(''); //set this to 'auto' if you havent set heights specifically in css, as in my fiddle
       return; //this makes it not work for heights less than 680
    }
    var allHeights = [];
    $('.sh').each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        allHeights.push(thisHeight);
    });
    var highestHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, allHeights);
    $('.sh').height(highestHeight);
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle, try resizing the result window to see it work.
https://jsfiddle.net/649n8dmc/

Comment: Hi Arathi, the updated version doesn't work anymore. The first one did but not on resize.

Comment: I am sorry, not sure what is wrong, so on resize is the width greater that 680? I have not tested this code, but just used the same code both on ready and on resize, the only additional condition being the if condition at the top.

Comment: The script should only work on > 680. It has to recalculate the hightest height on resizing > 680. See https://jsfiddle.net/ctb9f3c1/4/ Start with red block, then resize till it gets yellow, then the both divs still have the same height while they shouldn't. Hope I'm clear :(

Comment: I have added a line inside the height condition check that resets the height back to what it was.

Comment: Ah, its still not perfect. When the block is red it doesn't gets resized when you play with the width. The text div is getting higher and lower but it doesn't refresh the red block height. Its not critical thow. At least the viewport script works

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script like this

```
var max = 680;

function resizeTheHeights() {
 // Returns width of browser viewport
 var width = $( window ).width();
 if (width <= max) {
  return;
 }

 // then add the rest of your function body...
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that resizeTheHeight() is throttled or debounced. Some browsers fires millions of resize events when user resize the window, which means that the target function would be called million times.